# RStudio Server: Cannot connect to service

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server

I tried to set up RStudio Server on a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit machine. I followed the instructions but when I browsed the portal, I was told with a popup that I wasn't able to connect to the service.

From traceback:

```
13737 socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
13737 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
13737 sendto(3, "<11>Oct 14 14:27:59 rsession-roo"..., 283, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 283
13737 exit_group(1)                     = ?
13737 +++ exited with 1 +++
13708 <... rt_sigtimedwait resumed> )   = 17
13708 wait4(13737, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 13737
13708 rt_sigtimedwait([INT QUIT TERM CHLD], NULL, NULL, 8 <unfinished ...>
13729 connect(9, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/tmp/rstudio-rsession/root"}, 28) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
13728 connect(9, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/tmp/rstudio-rsession/root"}, 28) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

From /var/log/syslog:

```
Oct 14 14:26:42 iZ28xtxldicZ rsession-root[13730]: ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied); OCCURRED AT: int main(int, char* const*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:3003; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:3004
Oct 14 14:26:52 iZ28xtxldicZ rserver[13708]: ERROR system error 111 (Connection refused) [request-uri=/rpc/client_init]; OCCURRED AT: void rstudio::core::http::LocalStreamAsyncClient::handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/LocalStreamAsyncClient.hpp:84; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::server::session_proxy::{anonymous}::logIfNotConnectionTerminated(const rstudio::core::Error&, const rstudio::core::http::Request&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerSessionProxy.cpp:269
```

Anyone knows what's happening here?

PS: At first it was telling ENOENT over a path to the temp folder, and now it's telling something different after I created it manually.